# Login without Password

Tags: login

In Wordpress I need to add a filter where user role subscriber just put his email address in form to login, no need for password, just check if the email is for a subscriber and redirect him to a specific page, I tried many solutions but I didn't get it,
Thanks

Comment: That is asking for all sorts of abuses. You could probably write a plugin to do that but I strongly recommend against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add an [authenticate](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/authenticate/) filter to handle the email and no password case with a higher priority than the default wp_authenticate_email_password handler. e.g. (untested)

```php
function wpse_380353_authenticate_email_no_password( $user, $email, $password ) {
    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) || ( $user instanceof WP_User ) ) {
        // Already handled by a higher-priority filter
        return $user;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $email ) && is_email( $email ) && empty( $password ) ) {
        // This is an email login with empty password
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );

        if ( $user && ! is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
            // TODO: Verify that the user is someone you'd want to login without
            // a password. For now, let's reject anyone who can edit posts.
            if ( $user->has_cap( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
                $error = new WP_Error();
                // TODO: localize the error message
                $error->add( 'empty_password',
                    '<strong>Error</strong>: This user requires a password.' );
                return $error;
            }

            // We'll allow this user to login without a password.
            // Return the user object and the calling code will handle the login.
            return $user;
        }
        // else could not fetch the user by email address.
        // You'll probably now get a 'password field is empty' error
        // from a later filter.
        // TODO: If you want a different error then generate it here.
    }

    return $user;
}

// Add an authenticate filter with a higher priority (= lower number) than
// wp_authenticate_email_password which has priority 20.
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wpse_380353_authenticate_email_no_password', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code seems not working,

Comment: I'd got the priority number mixed up: lower number = higher priority. Fixed. Apart from that it all works for me.

Comment: it works, thanks

Comment: Can I make a form where subscriber put his email and redirect to a specific link ? is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress core is full of surprises. You can do many things with that.

To provide a password less login to desired user role, you can modify how WordPress handles user login authentication. There is a filter named `authenticate`, which you can use to hook in, and extend the authorization process to enable that.

WordPress itself hook into this callback with 3 separate function -

- `wp_authenticate_cookie` - This validates if the user is already logged-in.
- `wp_authenticate_username_password` - This validate user_name/password combo
- `wp_authenticate_email_password` - This validates email/password combo.

Above functions are hooked with a priority of `30`.
You can hook with a function here with higher priority and check if any of these validation returns a `WP_Error` object. For empty password, the error code would be `empty_password`. If the error and error code matches, you can perform further validation to test if there is a user with that login/email, and if he is a subscriber.

Sounds Good? Here's the code -

```php
function wpse_password_less_login_authentication( $user, $username, $password ) {
    if (! is_wp_error($user) && 'empty_password ' !== $user->get_error_code()) {
        return $user;
    }

    if (strpos($username, '@')) {
        $find_user = get_user_by( 'email', $username );
    } else {
        $find_user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
    }

    if ( $find_user && ! is_wp_error( $find_user ) && in_array( 'subscriber', $find_user->roles, true ) ) {
        return $find_user;
    }
    
    return $user;
}
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wpse_password_less_login_authentication', 40, 3 );
```

This function should go inside your themes `functions.php` (or included files) or inside an active plugin file.

Comment: Thanks, but this code seems not working

Comment: It needed one small tweak and now this works for me too.